# How to remove a tabpage from a context menu

Tags: c#, contextmenu, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have written the code to display a context menu on right click of my tabpages. How would I go about actually removing the tabpage when the user clicks "Remove Tab" from the context menu? I have gotten this far. (unloadProfile is my context menu item). I am unsure how to get the tabpage the context menu is associating with to remove it. Any help is appreciated.

```
// My Context Menu
private void tabControl_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            // iterate through all the tab pages
            for (int i = 0; i < tabControl.TabCount; i++)
            {
                // get their rectangle area and check if it contains the mouse cursor
                Rectangle r = tabControl.GetTabRect(i);
                if (r.Contains(e.Location))
                {
                    // show the context menu here
                    this.contextMenuStrip1.Show(this.tabControl, e.Location);
                }
            }
        }
    }

// Context menu click event
private void unloadProfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // iterate through all the tab pages
        for (int i = 0; i < tabControl.TabCount; i++)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is a correct way to do this, but it works.

In the tabControl1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) event, set the Tag property of menustrip to the TabPage selected.

```
// show the context menu here
this.contextMenuStrip1.Tag = this.tabControl1.TabPages[i];
this.contextMenuStrip1.Show(this.tabControl1, e.Location);
```

And in the removeTabToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) event remove the Tab Page using Tag property

```
this.tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(this.contextMenuStrip1.Tag as TabPage);
```

A null check will be good :) Hope it helps.

Comment: - Wow, I am blown away by this.. Part of the code doesn't make sense to me, such as using the `Tag` as a `TabPage`. but apparently it works! +1 For Success :)